# ListView control rendering issue with Groups, CheckBoxes and View mode SmallIcon

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Microsoft MSDN site has next [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewgroup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8): "Any groups assigned to a ListView  control appear whenever the ListView.View property is set to a value other than View.List."

My problem is that i like to have View set to SmallIcon.

In this mode ListView control is shifted left, and CheckBoxes are covered by left edge

How to solve this issue, or at least how is possible to shift rendering of control to the right. My OS is Windows XP Service Pack 3.

It looks like that ListView items with Groups and CheckBoxes shows correctly only when View set to Details.

[image]

**Updated:** Setting ListViewGroup.Header property will resets scroll position to 0. Is there are any other workaround except saving scroll position before assignment and restoring it afterwards.

Comment: No repro, works fine on Win7.  You'll need to document the operating system and perhaps post a screen shot.

Comment: Yes, works fine on Vista as well.

Comment: I've also seen this behavior on XP; the same ListView on Vista/7 has the checkboxes pushed very close to the left edge (like 1px away), which isn't ideal either.

Comment: can you share the source code for this listview or tell me how you achieved this IU

Answer (score 0):

try the following open source project to enhance the WinForm ListView. http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html